# Facebook with login in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

how to Facebook with login in website and also fetch user data like that - First Name, last name, birth date, location, profile pic, etc.

Comment: read Facebook developer tools https://developers.facebook.com/products/login

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this instruction :
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-FaceBook-account-in-ASPNet-Website.aspx

There is code and demo available.
Also be sure to create facebook app also.